# session variable getting unset after every ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

i am trying to modify a session variable in each ajax call (so as to later retreive only the new content from db ) but one session variable $_SESSION['s'] is getting unset in every alt. ajax call ! however the unmodified session variable $_SESSION["iuser"] is working fine . I am testing this on localhost / wamp and coding in npp .

```
   <?php
session_start();
//if(isset($_SESSION["s"]))
$in=$_SESSION["s"];
//echo $_SESSION['sid'];
$link=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("secure_scrapbook") or die("Sorry :( Connection Error");
$query="Select data,user,id from public where public=1 && id>'$in' ORDER BY id DESC";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$i=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$_SESSION["s"]=$i["id"];
//echo $_SESSION['sid'];
if(!($_SESSION["s"]==$in))
{echo 0;
echo $in;
echo $_SESSION["iuser"];
echo $_SESSION["s"];
echo "check<br>";
}
?>
```

--jquery /ajax -----

```
<script>
        setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
 url: "gets.php",
 type : "get" ,
  dataType : 'html',
 success : function(data){
 //$("#public").html(data);}
        $("#public").html(data+$("#public").html()+'-');}
});}, 5000); //5 seconds
 </script>
```

Comment: are you sure you're not getting `headers already sent`? I feel there is whitespace characters before your `<?php` and thus the session isn't getting started at all.

Comment: no problem with session as i echoed session_id and it is same in every call . even the 'iuser' session variable is echoing the same value !

Comment: Try without ajax CALL , go directly on ,that php and Execute it there.Check what is output.

Comment: make sure `$i["id"]` is not null, nor empty

Comment: You should probably check the value of what `$i["id"]` returns.

Comment: @PratikJoshi w/o ajax CALL it is printing the values fine (fine meaning as it should in the case )

Comment: @UnamataSanatarai  this is strange $id["id"] is not printing in every alternate call

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest you debug your calls like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (empty($_SESSION["s"])){
    echo 'EMPTY SESSION ';
    die;
}

$in = $_SESSION["s"];
$link=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("secure_scrapbook") or die("Sorry :( Connection Error");
$query="Select data,user,id from public where public=1 && id>'$in' ORDER BY id DESC";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$i=mysql_fetch_array($result);
if (empty($i["id"])){
    echo 'EMPTY $i';
    die;
}
$_SESSION["s"]=$i["id"];
//echo $_SESSION['sid'];
if(!($_SESSION["s"]==$in))
{echo 0;
echo $in;
echo $_SESSION["iuser"];
echo $_SESSION["s"];
echo "check<br>";
}
?>
```

Each time you get the message *EMPTY SESSION* or *EMPTY $i* check:

- the ajax headers and try to step-by-step track your problem.
- the element in the database does have an ID
- the $in is within the boundries of possible ID's
- the $in is a number

Comment: getting plenty of EMPTY SESSION . how to proceed ?

Comment: sorry to say, but comment out the `die;` after `echo 'EMPTY SESSION ';` and see what you get in return. Track down after what `$in` your session *dies*. Really, it's a step by step process :(

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    session_start();
    //if(isset($_SESSION["s"]))
    $in=$_SESSION["s"];
    //echo $_SESSION['sid'];
    $link=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("secure_scrapbook") or die("Sorry :( Connection Error");
    $query="Select data,user,id from public where public=1 && id>'$in' ORDER BY id DESC";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    if($i=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $_SESSION["s"]=$i["id"];
        //echo $_SESSION['sid'];
        if(!($_SESSION["s"]==$in))
        {
            echo 0;
            echo $in;
            echo $_SESSION["iuser"];
            echo $_SESSION["s"];
            echo "check<br>";
        }
    }
    else
        echo "No more Data in table";
?>
```

Try this and if "No more Data in table" is echoed, it means that your db doesn't have any data satisfying the conditions you set.

One more thing, seeing your code it looks like $_SESSION["s"] will never be equal to $in so i guess you don't need to use the if condition.